# Flash stock DD-WRT on WSR-1166DD router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I bought a bunch of Buffalo WSR-1166DD routers because I saw they had DD-WRT on them. Upon closer inspection they have DD-WRT NXT which seems severely gimped. Has anyone had luck flashing stock/base DD-WRT on these or any other routers that come with DD-WRT NXT initially?

Comment: Does that make sense that a router is DD-WRT NXT compatible but not DD-WRT compatible? I'm not familiar with the nature of NXT.

Comment: Ramhound, the WHR-1166DD is also compatible with DD-WRT. Those two look physically different though.

Comment: Ramhound, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: I hadn't found any references to what specific chips those routers use. That's what I was asking about. **Edit:** I found what chips the WHR and the WZR use but not the WSR.

Comment: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Buffalo_AirStation_WSR-1166DHP.  "Buffalo WSR-1166DD FCC ID: FDI000000028" which is the same id the 1166DHP has.

Comment: Since comments are not designed to be kept.  I have deleted my other comments.  Everything I discovered is from a google search looking at the DD-WRT website, or the OpenWRT website.

Comment: Start with the NXT pages .. they have a supported hardware page.. and there lists the chips used (1) and (2) additionally while the *gui* is may be "gimped" they clearly reference on the start page that commands are available via CLI (now called UCI) which extend the functionality .. they give setting up static route as example...http://www.dd-wrt.com/nxt/wiki/doku.php?id=hardware:supported_devices and  (3) search for the function you wanted DD-WRT to perform, there may be ways to do so through the UCI.

Comment: TG2, thanks for the UCI reference. Pointed me in the right direction to get the information I needed off the router (getting the wireless password and ap security information).

Answer (score 0):

**Open-WRT**
Looks like the closest I'm getting is Open-WRT. Below the are the most relevant links if anyone else wants to try:

- https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/buffalo/wsr-1166dhp
- https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=62413